# How to install drivers for GeForce FX 5500 in Ubuntu 12.10?

Tags: drivers, nvidia, 12.10

I can't manage to install drivers for my video card. Similar questions didn't help me, because they were outdated. What I tried were to following:

- Tried `sudo apt-get install nvidia-173`, dependency issues
- Tried to downgrade xorg packages to solve this dependency issue, no luck, they were still present
- Tried to download driver from NVIDIA's homepage, and install that

The last one seems the only way that could succeed, but while installing I'm getting errors related to kernel sources. I did `sudo apt-get install linux-source`.

```
ERROR: If you are using a Linux 2.4 kernel, please make sure
       you either have configured kernel sources matching your
       kernel or the correct set of kernel headers installed
       on your system.

       If you are using a Linux 2.6 kernel, please make sure
       you have configured kernel sources matching your kernel
       installed on your system. If you specified a separate
       output directory using either the "KBUILD_OUTPUT" or
       the "O" KBUILD parameter, make sure to specify this
       directory with the SYSOUT environment variable or with
       the equivalent nvidia-installer command line option.

       Depending on where and how the kernel sources (or the
       kernel headers) were installed, you may need to specify
       their location with the SYSSRC environment variable or
       the equivalent nvidia-installer command line option.
```

Log entries:

```
Using: nvidia-installer ncurses user interface
-> License accepted.
-> Installing NVIDIA driver version 173.14.28.
-> Running distribution scripts
   executing: '/usr/lib/nvidia/pre-install'...
-> done.
-> The distribution-provided pre-install script failed!  Continue installation
   anyway? (Answer: Yes)
-> Not probing for precompiled kernel interfaces.
-> Performing CC sanity check with CC="cc".
-> Kernel source path: '/lib/modules/3.5.0-17-generic/build'
-> Kernel output path: '/lib/modules/3.5.0-17-generic/build'
```

I'm pretty sure it can be done by the official NVIDIA installer, but I didn't see any help (which is useful in my case) on the internet.